Submit button always says "Continue" instead of "Pay" when using Google Pay via Paypal with a German Google account
We are integrating Google Pay via Paypal Checkout. We want the following flow:
Payment Request Dialog -> user authorizes payment amount -> show order review page -> user places order -> capture payment amount
The problem

The label of the main button in the payment sheet dialog always says "Pay" (German: Bezahlen) instead of "Continue" (German: Weiter).
This is the code (we are using the official web component library, the cfg is some basic config coming from Paypal that we just pass on to the paymentRequest). We are handling more callbackIntents than shown here, but this is just the MVP that should work:
btn.onPaymentAuthorized = (data) => { console.log("auth", data) }
btn.onLoadPaymentData = (paymentData) => { console.log("load", paymentData) }

btn.buttonType = "checkout"
btn.buttonLocale = "de"

btn.paymentRequest = {
    apiVersion: cfg.apiVersion,
    apiVersionMinor: cfg.apiVersionMinor,
    merchantInfo: cfg.merchantInfo,
    allowedPaymentMethods: cfg.allowedPaymentMethods,
    callbackIntents: ["PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION"],
    transactionInfo: {
        countryCode: cfg.countryCode,
        currencyCode: "EUR",
        totalPrice: "19.99",
        totalPriceStatus: "ESTIMATED", // <-- should set button label to "Continue"
    }
}


The docs
According to the docs, the submit button text ist controlled either by the CheckoutOption-option or the totalPriceStatus.
We can set CheckoutOption to COMPLETE_IMMEDIATE_PURCHASE so that users view a Pay button instead of a Continue button within the Google Pay selector.
But that's not what we want. Instead, we want the deault bahaviour:
By default the CheckoutOption is set to DEFAULT and depends on the totalPriceStatus status.
So since our totalPriceStatus is ESTIMATED and the checkoutOption is implicitly DEFAULT, I would expect to see a Continue button , but instead it always says Pay no matter what.

The weird part
I cannot recreate this in a Fiddle. If I take the exact same data and throw it in a fiddle, it works as expected.
The HTML:
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google-pay/button-element@latest/dist/index.umd.js"></script>

<google-pay-button button-type="checkout" environment="TEST"></google-pay-button>

The JS:
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('google-pay-button');

for (const button of buttons) {
  button.onLoadPaymentData = data => console.log("loaded", data)
  button.buttonLocale = 'de'

  button.paymentRequest = {
    apiVersion: 2,
    apiVersionMinor: 0,
    allowedPaymentMethods: [
        {
            type: "CARD",
            parameters: {
                "allowedAuthMethods": ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"],
                "allowedCardNetworks": ["MASTERCARD", "DISCOVER", "VISA", "AMEX"],
                "billingAddressRequired": true,
                "assuranceDetailsRequired": true,
                "billingAddressParameters": { "format": "FULL" }
            },
            tokenizationSpecification: {
                "type": "PAYMENT_GATEWAY",
                "parameters": {"gateway": "paypalppcp", "gatewayMerchantId": "XXXXXXXXXX" }
            }
        }
    ],
    merchantInfo: {
      // merchantOrigin: "...", -- left off in the fiddle
      // authJwt: "....", -- left off in the fiddle, comes from paypal
      merchantId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
      merchantName: "Our Name"
    },
    transactionInfo: {
      totalPriceStatus: 'ESTIMATED',
      totalPrice: '19.99',
      currencyCode: 'EUR',
      countryCode: 'DE',
    },
  };
}

The result:

Notice that the sheet language is now English instead of German even though it's the exact same browser session with the logged in Google account, and the test payment cards have changed.
So this seems now to be decoupled from Paypal since we left off the JWT token I guess? I'm not sure where exactly Paypal comes in.

The question
Why is this happening? Could this be a translation / i18n issue? Or might this even be an issue on Paypal's side?

Further context
Since we are based in Germany, we are legally required to display specific information (such as a Terms of Service link) alongside the submit button that initiates a payment. Additionally, there are strict regulations on how that button can be labeled. Because we cannot control these aspects within the payment sheet, we are unable to complete the purchase directly from there. Instead, we must redirect to a review page to display all the necessary information.
Furthermore, UX guidelines suggest adding the Google Pay button to the product page. However, due to GDPR regulations, this is not feasible without the user's consent.

Are you able to reproduce the issue if you add callbackIntents to your fiddle example?

@Domi Dang it... what a rookie mistake! Yes, it actually is reproducable if I add callbackIntents: ["PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION"] - genuinely hadn't noticed that this was missing. Here's the whole fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adcbz5p8/

Unfortunately what you are trying to achieve is not possible if callbackIntents are involved. If callbackIntents are part of the payload, Google Pay shows the "old" UI where in your case "Bezahlen" is shown due to SCA. We are currently working on bringing the callback functionality to the new UI as well. After that, the text on the button is solely defined by the value of checkoutOption.

@Domi Oh, I see! Thanks a lot for looking into it. It was driving me crazy! Yeah, the SHIPPING_ADDRESS and SHIPPING_OPTION intents are the features we’re most interested in since they make the checkout process as smooth as possible (under German regulations). Just to clarify: The authorize now/capture later flow would still work without callbackIntents, but the UI would be in English and it would only work if the capture amount stays the same, so it wouldn't trigger SCA -- did I get that right? Also, do you happen to know the ETA for the migration?

Correct. You can also implement a "authorize now/capture later" flow without callbackIntents. (Note: Google Pay is not involved in the authorization. It just provides a token and then the gateway is responsible for the processing). Also, if SCA (like 3DS) is triggered or not is up to the PSP. (Example: SCA should always be triggered for a Google Pay FPAN transaction). No, the UI shouldn't be in english. The Google Pay sheet should use the browser language.

@Domi, thanks for the clarification! From what I understood from the PayPal docs, the SCA process is managed by Google Pay, since we need to call initiatePayerAction on the Google bindings in that case. But yes, your explanation makes more sense. As for the UI: Yes, my browser language is indeed English, but I thought the payment sheet would use the language set in the Google account, or perhaps the locale set on the Button. At least that's how it seems to work in the 'old' UI when callbackIntents is set, which, again, got me quite confused. Anyway, thanks again, I appreciate your help!
